# Scatter Plot with Y depending on X

Tags: data-visualization, interaction, scatterplot

Does a scatter plot make sense if our Y variable is a part of the sum of the X variable? For example, say:

```
X : is the total time we spent driving to work 
Y : is the time spent waiting at stop lights
```

X is

```
X = Y + (time in transit) + (time spent part) + (etc.)
```

If we were to plot a simple case of this:

```
x <- 1:100
y <- 1:100
y_changed <- y + runif(100, 1,10)

plot(x, y)
points(y, y_changed)
```

[image]

In the above case, we basically have X = Y + Z (where Z is a value from 1 to 10).

Would we ever get anything that isn't a positive linear relationship in our plot? If so, does the final scatter plot have any real meaning that we don't already know?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "make sense"? After all, there is no barrier to constructing the scatterplot of any batch of $(X,Y)$ values.

Comment: I guess I mean two things, is there any value in plotting something like this (i.e. is there any way that we wouldn't get a linear correlation)? Also, when someone sees a graph like this, would it make intuitive sense to them? It seems to me that it takes a bit more thinking to reason through this type of plot.

Comment: Your second question might be better addressed on a psychology forum.  As far as the first one goes, since $X$ is $Y$ plus other stuff, the appearance of the scatterplot depends on the other stuff -- you haven't supplied any information that would be useful for answering your question.

Comment: I'm under the impression that it doesn't matter what the other stuff is. If the "other stuff" (call it Z) is 0, then we get a positive linear relationship. If it isn't, it will still basically be linear. None of our values can be less than 0. I've edited my initial question with a test case.

Comment: That impression isn't generally correct.  For instance, if the other stuff  tends to be close to $-(X+Y),$ then their sum with $Y$ equals $-X,$ giving a strong *negative* relationship with $X.$  That's why you need to be more specific.  Your question about "real meaning" is just too vague to be answerable.

Comment: I agree with @whuber, but I think the question is the wrong question any way. Given real data and a specific purpose, we could discuss in detail, but in abstraction this plot is unlikely to be helpful. A plot of time at lights versus total or %time at lights versus total might be of more use.

Comment: In the example above, if $Z > 0$ then I don't think we can get a negative relationship. However, the point on abstraction makes sense. If I need further help with my actual data, I'll create a new post and link it here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason it should not "make sense", although that depends on your definition of "making sense" ... I think it is better to look at your example:

- Maybe better to plot *proportion of time spent waiting for lights* against *total time in transit*? But, of course, that depends on **which question do you want to ask from the data**. Formulate that question, then make a plot answering it ... if you have two questions, maybe two plots ...

Also have a look at the comments thread!